# Does column validation effectively disable all workflows?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, error, 2019, column-validation

I'm looking for confirmation that this is a problem with SharePoint in general and not just my farm, and to document this in the StackExchange knowledgebase.

I also want to figure out, does this affect other farms?  Other versions of SharePoint?  I can't find much info online documenting the issue and it is a pretty major bug.  Any guidance the community could provide would be fantastic.

I'm working in a SharePoint 2019 on prem environment.  I never noticed this problem before but have no ability to test on other environments to confirm.

**Problem:**
Whenever I have column validation present on the list and one of those validation checks does not pass. No workflow can run on the list, even if it is not trying to update the list item or change the column that is failing to validate.

**To reproduce the problem:**

1. Set up a custom list, I added a "Due Date" column to mine of type DateTime.
2. Add a SP2013 workflow to the list that updates some values in the list item and just ends, very simple workflow.  Mine also sends an email. I also have the workflow trigger manually.
3. Run the workflow a couple times to make sure it is working.
4. Now add column validation to the list.  (I am talking about the validation available by going to the list settings, clicking the name of the column and scrolling down to the column validation section, expanding it and adding in a formula and message.)  I added two points of validation to my list:

   - Due Date could not be in the past.
   - Title could not start or end with a space or contain any characters disallowed by a document name.

- Here is the code for my two different fields of validation, in case that turns out to matter.

```
=IF([Due Date]<=TODAY(),TRUE)
```

And

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(34),Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(39),Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("<",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(">",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("?",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("\",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("|",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("$",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(";",Title)),TRUE),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("~",Title)),TRUE),
TRIM(Title)=Title)
```

5. Add a new item that passes validation, but will fail validation later on.  i.e. a due date that is today.
6. Run your workflow, it should still work at this point.
7. Come back tomorrow, now the due date is invalid, and run your workflow ... In my environment this throws an unhandled exception in the workflow that contains the error message "List data validation failed."
   There are other ways to get list items that fail validation, not just date based validation, for example adding a new validation rule can cause existing items to be in a failed validation state until they get updated.

So it seems to me that in a lot of real world examples of column validation, using the validation mechanism built into SharePoint effectively disables the ability to have workflows on the same list.  I can understand the need to not break validation if the workflow is trying to update the actual column being validated but I am completely surprised by the fact that the workflow doesn't run at all and that it doesn't matter what the workflow is trying to do, it just always fails.

Is this behavior the same for others? Have I misunderstood some key part of it?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to update the list item within designer workflow?

Comment: Tried it both with a workflow that is updating the list item (changing the value of a different column) and with a workflow that just sends an email ... nothing else.  Neither workflow is capable of running when the validation is in a failed state.